# How to convert to third person

Tags: academic-writing

> I was caught between two worlds of being too cautious because I did not want to upset my peers and as well being too cautious might not add value to my peers

How to convert to third person

Comment: You should show us your attempt. You should also explain why you think this is difficult.

Comment: In order to help rewrite this, it would useful to know: what is the context? What are you being cautious about? Could you include the previous two sentences, and the following two sentences?